# Test Get method using MockMvc and Mockito

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, mockmvc

I'm working on writing test case using MockMvc and Mokito.

Assume I have a list of order:

```
{
   {
    "order_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "price": 11.0,
    "order_status": "Pending",
   },
    {
    "order_id": 2,
    "user_id": 2,
    "price": 12.0,
    "order_status": "Cancelled",
   }, 
   {
    "order_id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "price": 13.0,
    "order_status": "Delivered",
   },
}
```

The column **order_id** is **unique** since I set it as primary key. But one user can have multiple orders so the column user_id can appear multiple times.

When I tried the endpoint `/api/order/getOrders/user/{user_id}` in **Postman** (For example, I set user_id = 1). The response is exactly same what I expected:

```
{
   {
    "order_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "price": 11.0,
    "order_status": "Pending",
   },
   {
    "order_id": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "price": 13.0,
    "order_status": "Delivered",
   },
}
```

However, when I tried to write the unit test case using MockMvc and Mockito. It always return all the orders. Here is my code:

```
List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();

Order order1 = new Order(1, 1, 11.0, "Pending");
Order order2 = new Order(2, 2, 12.0, "Cancelled");
Order order3 = new Order(3, 1, 13.0, "Shipped");

orderList.add(order1);
orderList.add(order2);
orderList.add(order3);

Mockito.when(orderService.getOrdersUserId(1)).thenReturn(orderList);
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/order/getOrders/user/{user_id}", 1).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)));
```

The test is failed because the response include all 3 items. I believe that I was wrong by using `thenReturn(orderList)` but I have no idea to fix it.
Can someone let me know how can I fix it, please?

Answer (score 0):

The order list that you return has all three orders in it so it's always going to return all of them. If you are mocking the behaviour then just add orders 1 and 3

```
List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();

Order order1 = new Order(1, 1, 11.0, "Pending");
Order order2 = new Order(2, 2, 12.0, "Cancelled");
Order order3 = new Order(3, 1, 13.0, "Shipped");

orderList.add(order1);
orderList.add(order3);
```

Comment: So we test it by adding manually? Do we have any solutions when I perform API Endpoints then receive the response as I expect?

Comment: Yes. You are testing the endpoint not the service. The service is mocked so you are mimicking the behaviour of your service when you ask it for orders for user id 1